# how to pass a named vector or two vectors as arguments to dplyr::recode

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'd like to pass either a named vector or two vectors to dplyr::recode.
Let's say I've got:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
x <- c("customer", sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE))
recode_tbl <- tibble(letter = letters[1:3], fruit = c("apple", "banana", "cranberry"))
```

What I'd like to do is use the columns of recode_tbl to recode x, without having to specify the pairs manually as:

```
recode(x, a = "apple", b = "banana", c = "cranberry")
```

Something like:

```
recode(x, as.name(recode_tbl$letter) = recode_tbl$fruit)
```

That obviously doesn't work. I'm not averse to trying NSE but if someone could get the ball rolling that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do this in `base R`

```
x1 <- unname(setNames(recode_tbl$fruit, recode_tbl$letter)[x])
x1[is.na(x1)] <- x[is.na(x1)]
```

---

Or use `do.call` with `recode`

```
do.call(dplyr::recode, c(list(x), setNames(recode_tbl$fruit, recode_tbl$letter)))
#[1] "customer"  "apple"     "banana"    "banana"    "cranberry" "apple"
#[8] "cranberry" "cranberry" "banana"    "banana"    "apple"
```

---

Or when passing a named vector to rename levels use !!! to splice

```
recode(x, !!!setNames(recode_tbl$fruit, recode_tbl$letter))
```

Comment: @Sotos I guess it is.  Confirmed, it is (used `dplyr_0.7.0`)

Comment: I got a bit confused on the baseR-like style of the answer

Comment: @Sotos I think there should be a way with `purrr` using `map`.

Comment: I have been digging into `purrr` lately. Those `map*` functions are really useful.

Comment: @akrun: I want a vectorised way rather than using `purrr::map`, even though I'm a big fan of purrr.

Comment: @biomiha Okay, then the `do.call` option would be useufl

Comment: Very helpful, so many thanks.


I needed to do this for columns in a tibble.


It took a while for me to work it out, possibly because I was being a little dim, but this works :- 


`xt <- tibble(Customer = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                                    20, replace = TRUE))`


`do.call(dplyr::recode,
         c(list(xt$Customer), 
           setNames(recode_tbl$fruit, recode_tbl$letter)))`

Comment: how might we do this inside dplyr mutate?

Comment: ok i figured it out - it's mutate(variable = recode(variable, !!!namedlist)

Comment: @ArthurYip  Sorry, I forgot to answer your comment.  Glad that you got it resolved

Comment: Even though the question is quite old already: You can get around do.call by using the !!! operator. So this is the shortest call with recode: `recode(x, !!!setNames(recode_tbl$fruit, recode_tbl$letter))`